# How to Invoke anonymous javascript function on object in 1 line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, anonymous-function

I am learning about javascript anonymous functions and scope and am trying to understand something but have become a bit stuck.

I have the following three functions:

```
var funcA = function (value) {
    test = value;
};

var funcB = function (value) {
    this.test = value;
};

var funcC = function (func,value) {
    var item = {};
    //single line invocation
}
```

I am trying to write a single line of javascript (where it says `//single line invocation`) such that the result of the two following calls will differ, instead of having the same effect:

```
funcC(funcA, "set");
funcC(funcB, "set");
```

Since funcB is referencing `this.test` instead, it makes sense that it will be changing a local (instance) value so we can make use of the "item" object in funcC. I tried doing some anonymous function "stuff" like:

```
item.(function(func,value){func(value)})(func, value);
```

However I have not had any luck in terms of the statements resulting in different outcomes. (i.e. when I run my code using node(.js) the `test` and `this.test` values both change).

Any help on understanding this better would be great.

Thanks in advance,

ParagonRG

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to tell it the instance to work on.

```
funcB.call(item, value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an anonymus function as a object property. You want to do

```
var item = {"f": func};
item.f(value);
// item.test == value now
```

right? The way JavaScript does this is the [`.call()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
func.call(item, value);
// with the difference that item has no "f" property here
```

You can also use `call` with anonymous function expressions:

```
(function(val){ this.test = val; }).call(item, value);
// yet this equivalent looks much cleaner:
item.test = value;
```